# проверка из базы + добавление

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Js:

```
<script>
function checkAvailability() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    $("#Check").on("click", function(){
        jQuery.ajax({ 
            url: "check_availability.php", 
            data: {
                username: $("#username").val(), 
                date_order: $("#date_order").val() 
            },
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) { 
                $("#user-availability-status").html(data);
            }, 
            error:function (){} 
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

check_availability.php

```
if(!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["date_order"])) {
    $sql = "
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM name 
        WHERE 
            username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' AND 
            date_order='" . $_POST["date_order"] . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
        echo "<span class='status-not-available'> Username Not Available.</span>"; 
    } else { 
        echo "<span class='status-available'> Username Available.</span>"; 
    } 
} else{
    echo "Одно из полей пустое";
}

$result = mysql_query($sql) || die(mysql_error());
```

тут идёт просто проверка из базы. необходимо после проверки добавить в базу) как сделать ?

Js:

```
function checkAvailability() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    $("#Check").on("click", function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : "check_availability.php",
            data : {
                username : $("#username").val(),
                date_order : $("#date_order").val()
            },

            type : "POST",
            success : function (data) {
                $("#user-availability-status").html(data);
            },
            error : function () {}
        });

        function insertUsername() {

            jQuery.ajax({
                url : "add.php",
                data : {
                    username : $("#username").val(),
                    date_order : $("#date_order").val()
                },
                type : "POST",
                success : function (data) {
                    $("#user-availability-status").html(data);

                },

                error : function () {}

            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: А что Вы пытались сделать, какие варианты коды Вы писали? Насколько я понимаю, эта функция только проверяет. А где написанная Вами функция, которая пытается добавить?

Comment: Кто тут видит проверку из базы?

Comment: да я нуб) ничего не писал:) добавил

Comment: Илья, ну так надо бы... Мы готовы Вам помочь решить задачу, а не решить за Вас...

Comment: В качестве направления: приведенный Вам код проверяет содержимое базы. Далее, если ajax возвращает отрицательный ответ (Username not Available.), то надо послать второй ajax на создание... Как Вы это сделаете?

Comment: $sql = 'INSERT INTO name(username,data_order) 
 VALUES("'.$username.'", "'.$data_order'")'; $username = $_POST['username']; $data_order = $_POST'[data_order'];

Comment: помогите, ребятушки)))

Comment: Чудесно... Правильно. Это вставит информацию в БД. Вот Вы все сами и сделали :) Только местами поменяйте - сначала переменные заполнить, а уже потом их в sql

Comment: а между чем вставить? я путаюсь в этих кавычках

Answer (score 1):

Отвечать не буду. Только распишу, что надо сделать.

надо проверить ответ ajax. И если ответ "not available" - послать новый запрос на создание.
Т.е. после `$("#user-availability-status").html(data);` надо вставить несколько строчек кода, проверяющих ответ. И, если `true`, то создать новую JS функцию, скажем `insertUsername()`, и пересылать дальнейший код туда.
Эта функция будет ОЧЕНЬ похожа на уже имеющуюся. И даже ajax будет похож. Только в PHP вместо `SELECT ... FROM` Вы напишите уже приведенную Вами `INSERT INTO`

Comment: понимаете, мне надо побыстрее) это я делаю для себя. я понимаю логику, но разбираться времени нет. для вас это 2 минуты) помогите плиз, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: if(!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["date_order"])) {
    $sql = "
       INSERT INTO name
        WHERE 
            username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' AND 
            date_order='" . $_POST["date_order"] . "'
           
    ";




           $result = mysql_query($sql);
           if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
               echo "<span class='status-not-available'> Username Not Available.</span>"; 
           }
           else{ 

               echo "<span class='status-available'> Username Available.</span>"; 
          } 

}
else{

    echo "Одно из полей пустое";

}

Comment: function insertUsername() {
     jQuery.ajax({ 
        url: "add.php", 
   data: { username: $("#username").val(), 
  
          
                date_order: $("#date_order").val() 
                

        },

        type: "POST",
 
         success:function(data){ 
            $("#user-availability-status").html(data);




 
        }, 
        error:function (){} 
    });
});
}

Comment: так ? можете это в нормальный вид привести?))) как это всё склеить? с этими точечками кавычечками

Comment: да, все правильно! Только вместо `$("#user-availability-status").html(data);` напиши, что должно происходить, когда пользователь создан. А также создай `add.php` и сделай там идентичный код, только вместо `SELECT` делай `INSERT INTO`, которую упоминал выше.

Comment: а что должно происходить ? пускай пишет, что данные добавлены. я обновил. не добавляются данные:(

Comment: Функция `insertUsername()` присутствует. Но Вы ее никак не вызываете, а должны вызывать после ajax ответа в `checkAvailability()`. А насчет "пускай пишет", то это в ответе `insertUsername()` надо поменять `$("#user-availability-status").html(data);` на `$("#user-availability-status").html('Username was added successfully');`